# iMovie on iPhone 4 : How to separate audio

Tags: iphone, imovie

How can I separate the audio from an existing video file on iPhone programatically?

Comment: If you're looking for an answer to a programming question, please ask on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). Programming questions are considered off-topic here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iMovie for iPhone 4 does not offer the ability to separate the audio from the video of a movie. It only allows one track of audio - either a background song *or* the audio from the clip you're using. If you click and hold on a clip it brings up the Clip Settings view where you can turn off the audio for the clip.

iMovie for iPhone 4 doesn't allow you to do anything programatically. If you're wanting to develop something with the iOS SDK to pull the audio from a movie I suggest editing your question and reading up on what you can do with [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/index.html)

Comment: k, how i mix the existing audio to existing video file pro-grammatically!!! any ideas!